# where to store helper functions?

Tags: php, oop, organization, code-organization

i've got a lot of functions i create or copy from the web.

i wonder if i should store them in a file that i just include into the script or should i store each function as a static method in a class.

eg. i've got a getCurrentFolder() and a isFilePhp() function.

should they be stored in a file as they are or each in a class:

Folder::getCurrent()
File::isPhp();

how do you do?

i know this is kinda a "as u want" question but it would be great with some advices/best practices

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, this is highly subjective matter however I would probably use a mix of your two options.

You have a class (say Helper) that has the `__call()` (and/or `__callStatic()` if you're using PHP 5.3+) [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), when a non defined [static] method is called it'll load the respective helper file and execute the helper function. Keep in mind though that including files decreases performance, but I believe the benefit you gain in terms of file organization far outweighs the tiny performance hit.

A simple example:

```
class helper {
    function __callStatic($m, $args) {
        if (is_file('./helpers/' . $m . '.php')) {
            include_once('./helpers/' . $m . '.php');
            return call_user_func_array($m, $args);
        }
    }
}

helper::isFilePhp(/*...*/); // ./helpers/isFilePhp.php
helper::getCurrentFolder(/*...*/); // ./helpers/getCurrentFolder.php
```

You can further optimize this snippet and even have several types of helpers (Folder, File) and so on, by adding a `__call[Static]()` magic method to each of your classes and implementing some logic in the folder/file structure of your helper files/functions.